# Make absolute positioned, centered div scroll without cutting off the first elements

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a list where items can get added or removed. The list needs to be vertically and horizontally centered to it's container. To do that I used the following style:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
```

When elements get added into the list, the user should be able to scroll up and down to view all the elements. But with what I have, the user can scroll but the top part of the list is cut off. I believe that is because of the transform and top 50% I have used.

How do I get the list div to center horizontally and vertically AND scroll without issues when the list overflows?

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/3547/) with what I have.

I'm using Angular 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `max-height` to `list` and set `overflow-y` to `auto` so that whenever list items increased, you will get a scroll inside it.

```
.list {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%; // Added
    overflow-y: auto;  // Added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the child wrapper scrollable and a fixed height like this:

`.list{
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}`